# Cannot start Zookeeper service on CentOS7

Tags: apache-kafka, centos7, apache-zookeeper

When trying to start zookeeper service I get the following

```
● zookeeper.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-04-02 16:19:24 EDT; 5min ago
  Process: 5201 ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.13-2.4.1/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4882 ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.13-2.4.1/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.13-2.4.1/config/zookeeper.properties (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 4882 (code=exited, status=127)

Apr 02 16:19:24 centos.localdomain systemd[1]: Started zookeeper.service.
Apr 02 16:19:24 centos.localdomain systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Apr 02 16:19:24 centos.localdomain systemd[1]: zookeeper.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 02 16:19:24 centos.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit zookeeper.service entered failed state.
Apr 02 16:19:24 centos.localdomain systemd[1]: zookeeper.service failed.
```

The zookeeper.service file is configured as follows

```
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=specadmin
ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.13-2.4.1/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh  /usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.13-2.4.1/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.13-2.4.1/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When trying to run zookeeper manually with the same user configured in the service file everything works fine.

Please advise

Comment: what are your findings for zookeeper exit code status 127?

Comment: exit code 127 is a systemd code that stands for "Unknown command". Not sure what is the meaning of this error in this contex

Comment: Can you share Zookeeper logs?

Comment: I am not sure the problem is the zookeeper because when running the command as configured in ExecStart in the service file everything works fine. Also when trying to start the zookeeper service, no zookeeper/kafka log files are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was related to the environment variables systemd uses.

Systemd uses a fixed $PATH variable and the changes that are made to the /etc/profile /etc/bashrc and the like are not applied to systemd.

Zookeeper runs java which needs to be part of the search path, but since systemd doesn't use the files where the search path is set, zookeeper start script couldn't find java.

I solved it by overriding the search path by adding Environment=PATH=... parameter in the zookeeper service file and adding all the required directories.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, but for me, the issue was related to a recent change that I made in the `zoo.cfg` file.

#### Issue

There was an extra space after the server URL which was not visible to the naked eye but I noticed that the Vim cursor was going 1 extra character.

`server.1:vmname.domain.com:2888:3888`

> Notice the extra space at the end.

There were no errors in the log about the incorrect server name, but after removing the space my Zookeeper service started.

`systemctl restart zookeeper.service`